# Javafx: using menu onclick

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am trying to make an fxml menu react to a click. Is this possible?

FXML:

```
<Menu fx:id="clickableMenu" 
      mnemonicParsing="false" 
      text="Menu" 
      onAction="#clickableMenu">
</Menu>
```

javafx:

```
@FXML Menu clickableMenu;

public void clickableMenu(ActionEvent e){
    System.out.println("Menu clicked");
}
```

This is my code, however when i launch the application, clicking on the menu produces no result. My guess is that the menu object has built in onaction behavior which is overriding my attempt. Is there any way around this without breaking menus everywhere else? In this specific case i do not care about preserving the built in onaction.

Comment: Are you sure this is a sensible UI decision? Why not use a `MenuItem`? Anyway - you may be able to get away with using [`onShowing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Menu.html#onShowingProperty).

Comment: I am guessing you are not using Gluon Scenebuilder. If not you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add: `@FXML`

```
@FXML
public void clickableMenu(ActionEvent e){
    System.out.println("Menu clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **@FXML** annotation to your method as below

```
@FXML
public void clickableMenu(){
    System.out.println("Menu clicked");
}
```

And you can remove the action event. Its not important.